# Making main content sit above a sticky footer

Tags: html, footer, sticky

I have setup a sticky footer and would like the main content to sit above it.

At the moment the content runs behind the footer, I'm wanting to get the `div#fullContainer` to sit above the footer. So that the red background sits above the footer.

I hope that makes sense.

```
<div id="fullContainer" style="background-color:red">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" >Text here</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer" id="container">footer content</div>


.footer {

    border-top:3px solid #ff0000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 180px;

}
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem (post the relevant code here; not a link). See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it - http://jsfiddle.net/Ballcheck/dp6LS/

Just added the following container class -

```
#fullContainer {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bungus! This is almost there now, appreciates your help. I still however get the text to show underneath the footer and the background color gets clipped: http://www.2welve.co.uk/mirrens/MIRRENS.jpg

I wanting to have the content scrolling in the fullContainer, like an iframe in a way... but css :-)

Comment: Haha, can't believe I didn't think of that! Cheers Bungus! You the dude! Totally appreciate all your help!